# Api design for cookies with two paths

Tags: rest, api, cookies, api-design

I'm currently working on an api where I use a refresh token saved in a cookie. My problem is that I need this refresh cookie on two paths, on the /refresh-token and on /logout, but as far as I know, I can only set one path attribute for one cookie. So should I use two cookies (sounds redundant for me) or should put both paths under something like /xyz >> /xyz/logout and /xyz/refresh-token so that I can set the path of the cookie to /xzy?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify a `PATH` (or simply set it to "/"), the cookie will be available in both places, assuming they're both on the same domain.

That being said, it will be accessible to other PATHs as well.

Comment: That's true, but that's the reason I only want it to be available on these two paths.